Rotten wood on the ground
What's the process to fix the wood? I am the first time home-owner and have an absolute zilch idea about the fix I need to do?
There is also a gap between the wood and the concrete. Should I caulk it?



Replace the rotten section with PT wood or plastic.

Yes , remove it and replace it.

What aspect of replacement are you unclear about? Please revise to ask something more specific.

@isherwood apologies.
What's the process to fix the wood? I am the first time home-owner and have an absolute zilch idea about the fix I need to do?
There is also a gap between the wood and the concrete. Should I caulk it?

Wood is usually nailed/screwed on, some times glued on.  I would bet on nails and they should be able to be pulled out with a pry bar/hammer.

thanks @crip659. There is also a visible gap between the wood and the concrete. Should I caulk it so the bugs don't find a way inside?

Caulk is the last thing you'll do, after removal, fitment, painting, reinstallation, etc. You might want to make a study of basic carpentry and woodworking. It's a bit much to explain every step of the process in an answer. Please take the [tour] so you know why hashing this out in a lengthy comment thread is inappropriate.

Any real wood in that location will be a continuing problem.  The design with the trim right on top of the stairs lends to constant wood rot from water.
It is not practical to explore removing possible water infiltration, so the smart decision would be to replace the rotted trim with something that is unaffected by water such as PVC trim.  It looks like the piece is a 1x4. you may need to purchase a full 8 foot board , but the fact that you can replace the rotted board and then never have to do it again is worth it.
The trim to the left looks like it is rotted too, maybe not as bad, but it will get bad. Use a pry bar to get under the edge of the the rotted wood. Pry up and continue to move the bar under the board as it comes loose.  Use  an oscillating saw to cut the vertical trim board and remove that as well.

I recommend that you cut out the trim at the red line. Start prying off the rotted board in the hole at the yellow lines and progress to the right prying the board off.  The purple arrow is what may be a nail that can help you determine where to pry as you progress pulling the board off.
Installation should be very evident. Use 2 inch [galvanized trim nails 4 to anchor the new board.  If installed correctly no bugs can get behind it. If you must use some polyurethane caulk to seal.

that was a super awesome reply! It is more like a tutorial! I will follow the steps you have suggested and let you know !! thanks

@HO123  And if you don't use the whole 8" board, save it because the rest of the wood around your house will eventually rot too.

Also, come back after you pry the rotten wood off and get us a picture of what it looks like underneath.
